# Do_While stuck in a loop Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to come up with a simple function to verify credentials before running other commands in ExchangeOnline.
Here is my problem(s):
IF I run the function with correct credentials the first time, it proceeds as expected. But if the credentials are wrong the first time, it get stuck in the "Get-credential" loop even when I provide the correct credentials. can't seem to find what the issue is.

```
    try
    {
    $Global:ErrorActionPreference ='Stop'
    $Usercreds= Get-Credential -Message "Please enter your Elevated account credentials" 
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $Usercreds
    Write-Host "`nSuccesfully authenticated" -ForegroundColor Green
    Get-MsolDomain
    }
    catch
    {
     #$Global:ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
     $Global:ErrMsg= $Error[0]
     Write-Host `n$Global:ErrMsg -ForegroundColor Red
    }
 }
 DO{
 verCreds
 }WHILE($Global:ErrMsg -like "Authentication Error: *")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `ErrMsg` is a global variable and it will always have the value of `Authentication Error:`  even you entered the credential right.

try to clear its value in the last step of the `try`

```
try
    {
    $Global:ErrorActionPreference ='Stop'
    $Usercreds= Get-Credential -Message "Please enter your Elevated account credentials" 
    Connect-MsolService -Credential $Usercreds
    Write-Host "`nSuccesfully authenticated" -ForegroundColor Green
    Get-MsolDomain
    $Global:ErrMsg = $null
    }
    catch
    {
     #$Global:ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
     $Global:ErrMsg= $Error[0]
     Write-Host `n$Global:ErrMsg -ForegroundColor Red
    }
 }
 DO{
 verCreds
 }WHILE($Global:ErrMsg -like "Authentication Error: *")
```

Comment: How did I miss that! Thanks Mahmoud!

Comment: you are welcome, please mark the reply as answer if it fixed your issue